Growth of Stone-Cech compactification
Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space and $\beta{X}$ be the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$. The set $\beta{X}\setminus X$ is known as the growth of $X$ in $\beta{X}$.
Is there any reference which discusses separation axioms in $\beta{X}\setminus X$?
Also I think my next question is elementary but I couldn't solve or provide a counterexample.

Is the growth $\beta{X}\setminus X$ a quotient space of $\beta{X}$?


Just a few ideas about your second question: Since $\beta X$ is compact and the remainder $\beta X \setminus X$ is T2, it is a quotient space, iff it is a continuous image of $\beta X$. I guess, in most cases this is false, for instance, if $X$ is not locally compact, hence $\beta X \setminus X$ is not compact. Or, if $X$ is connected, but $\beta X \setminus X$ not connected (for instance, $X = \mathbb R$. On the other hand, $\beta \omega_1 \setminus \omega_1$ consists of a single point, hence it is quotient space of $\beta \omega_1$.

About your first question: Firstly, I think it's not a good idea, to ask two rather unrelated questions in one post. Secondly, which separation axioms do you have in mind? Since $\beta X \setminus X$ is Tychonoff, it can be only normal and above?

Counterexample: $\beta \omega \setminus \omega$ is not a quotient space of $\beta \omega$, where $\omega$ is the countably infinite discrete space.
To prove this, note that any quotient of $\beta \omega$ is separable, because it is a continuous image of the separable space $\beta \omega$. Thus it remains to show that $\beta \omega \setminus \omega$ is not separable.
We use the construction of $\beta \omega$ as the Stone space of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$, whence $\beta \omega \setminus \omega$ consists of the non-principal ultrafilters on $\omega$. Assume for contradiction that $\{ u_1, u_2, \ldots \} \subseteq \beta \omega \setminus \omega$ is a countable dense subset. It is easy to recursively construct a sequence $\omega \supseteq A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \ldots$ of infinite subsets of $\omega$ such that $A_n \notin u_n$. Now take a strictly increasing sequence $(a_n) \subseteq \omega$ such that $a_n \in A_n$ and let $A = \{ a_n : n \in \omega \}$.
The set $A \subseteq \omega$ is infinite and $A \setminus A_n$ is finite for each $n \in \omega$, that is, $A \subseteq^* A_n$. It follows that $A \notin u_n$ for each $n \in \omega$. But this means that $A$ defines a non-empty clopen subset $[A] \subseteq \beta \omega \setminus \omega$ disjoint from $\{ u_1, u_2, \ldots \}$, which is a contradiction.

Would you define $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$?

Oh, $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is the power set of $\omega$.
